# Adding _includes and _layouts files to Jekyll directory

Tags: ruby, directory, frontend, jekyll, static-site

I'm new to Ruby and Jekyll, and I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.taniarascia.com/make-a-static-website-with-jekyll/) on how to create a static-site. I've reached the part where we're supposed to edit files inside the _includes and _layouts folders, but those folders don't appear in my directory. There is however a _site folder with an index.html file inside it, and it looks like that's what's showing when I run the website with 'jekyll serve'. Am I supposed to add these folders and files in myself, or should I edit _site/about/index.html to match what the tutorial has?

Here's a picture of what my current folder structure looks like:

[image: Directory Structure in VSCode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should add those folders and files yourself. Copy them from the theme repo and skip anyone you don't want to customize / override. The default theme config created by command `jekyll new` is https://github.com/jekyll/minima

The `_site` folder is being generated on the fly, it reflects the result of the customization.